In Polars - How do I more simply add two rows at the end of a dataframe one for total of each column and one for the percentages of that Totals row
For example
import polars as pl
df=pl.DataFrame({
    "Col Ind": ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    "Col A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Col B": [2,4,6,8,10],
    "Col C": [1,3,5,7,9],
    "Col D": [5,4,3,2,1] })

I would like to end up with a dataframe with a sixth row giving the total of each numeric column and then a seventh row with the percentage of the sum of those totals for each numeric column
To create the two new rows I have had to come up with the following very convoluted method:
first_col = df.select("Col Ind").to_series().append(pl.Series("temp", ["Total", "Percentage"]))
df = df.drop("Col Ind") 
cols = df.columns
expr = df.select(pl.sum(cols))
rowlist = list(expr.row(0))
full = sum(rowlist)
pc_row = []
for n in range(len(rowlist)):
    pc_row.append(int(rowlist[n] /full *100))

pc_dict = dict(zip(cols, pc_row))
pc_df = pl.DataFrame(pc_dict)
df = pl.concat([df,expr]) 
df = pl.concat([df,pc_df])
df.insert_column(0, first_col)

This works, but seems an awful lot of steps
IS there a simpler way?
Thankyou

In your example, the Percentage row is an integer and does not add up to 100. I am assume this is intentional, so I have followed that. If it was not, let me know and I can update the answer.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Col Ind": ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    "Col A": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "Col B": [2,4,6,8,10],
    "Col C": [1,3,5,7,9],
    "Col D": [5,4,3,2,1]
})

# Literal value of "Total", and sum all the columns except "Col Ind"
totals = df.select(pl.lit("Total").alias("Col Ind"), pl.exclude("Col Ind").sum())

# Literal value of "Percentage"
# and the total in all the columns except "Col Ind" / the grand total
# Multiply by 100 and cast to int per your example
percentages = totals.select(
    pl.lit("Percentage").alias("Col Ind"),
    (
        (pl.exclude("Col Ind") * 100 / pl.sum_horizontal(pl.exclude("Col Ind")))
        .cast(pl.Int64)
    )
)

pl.concat([df, totals, percentages], how="vertical")

# shape: (7, 5)
# ┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
# │ Col Ind    ┆ Col A ┆ Col B ┆ Col C ┆ Col D │
# │ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
# │ str        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
# ╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
# │ A          ┆ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 5     │
# │ B          ┆ 2     ┆ 4     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
# │ C          ┆ 3     ┆ 6     ┆ 5     ┆ 3     │
# │ D          ┆ 4     ┆ 8     ┆ 7     ┆ 2     │
# │ E          ┆ 5     ┆ 10    ┆ 9     ┆ 1     │
# │ Total      ┆ 15    ┆ 30    ┆ 25    ┆ 15    │
# │ Percentage ┆ 17    ┆ 35    ┆ 29    ┆ 17    │
# └────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

You will find computing totals and percentages much easier as separate columns, so I would suggest transposing your data. That will mean the percentage can be a float (and add up to 100), without making the rest of the data a float too (like it would here).
For example
transposed = df.drop("Col Ind").transpose(column_names=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
# shape: (4, 5)
# ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
# │ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ E   │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   │
# │ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   ┆ 8   ┆ 10  │
# │ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ 9   │
# │ 5   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
# └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

transposed.with_columns(
    total=pl.sum_horizontal("*"),
    percentage=pl.sum_horizontal("*") / pl.sum_horizontal("*").sum()
)
# shape: (4, 7)
# ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬────────────┐
# │ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ E   ┆ total ┆ percentage │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
# │ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ f64        │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╪════════════╡
# │ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 15    ┆ 0.176471   │
# │ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   ┆ 8   ┆ 10  ┆ 30    ┆ 0.352941   │
# │ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   ┆ 9   ┆ 25    ┆ 0.294118   │
# │ 5   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 15    ┆ 0.176471   │
# └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴────────────┘


import polars.selectors as cs

totals = df.select(cs.numeric().sum())
percentage = totals.select((pl.all() * 100 / pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all())).cast(pl.Int64))

pl.concat(
    [df] +
    [
        dfx.with_columns(pl.lit(namex).alias("Col Ind"))
        for dfx, namex in [(totals, "Total"), (percentage, "Percentage")]
    ],
    how="diagonal_relaxed"
)

shape: (7, 5)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ Col Ind    ┆ Col A ┆ Col B ┆ Col C ┆ Col D │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ A          ┆ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 5     │
│ B          ┆ 2     ┆ 4     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ C          ┆ 3     ┆ 6     ┆ 5     ┆ 3     │
│ D          ┆ 4     ┆ 8     ┆ 7     ┆ 2     │
│ E          ┆ 5     ┆ 10    ┆ 9     ┆ 1     │
│ Total      ┆ 15    ┆ 30    ┆ 25    ┆ 15    │
│ Percentage ┆ 17    ┆ 35    ┆ 29    ┆ 17    │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘


Many thanks for this.

A similar amount of steps, but your approach written as expressions could look like:
index = "Col Ind"
total = pl.exclude(index).sum()
percentage = (total / pl.sum_horizontal(total) * 100).cast(int)

df.select(
    pl.col(index).append(pl.lit("Total")).append(pl.lit("Percentage")),
    pl.exclude(index).append(total).append(percentage)
)

shape: (7, 5)
┌────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ Col Ind    ┆ Col A ┆ Col B ┆ Col C ┆ Col D │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ A          ┆ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 5     │
│ B          ┆ 2     ┆ 4     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     │
│ C          ┆ 3     ┆ 6     ┆ 5     ┆ 3     │
│ D          ┆ 4     ┆ 8     ┆ 7     ┆ 2     │
│ E          ┆ 5     ┆ 10    ┆ 9     ┆ 1     │
│ Total      ┆ 15    ┆ 30    ┆ 25    ┆ 15    │
│ Percentage ┆ 17    ┆ 35    ┆ 29    ┆ 17    │
└────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

